# How to gecode a character matrix of addresses and output just Long and Lat?

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggmap

I have an n x 1 list of addresses (whose class is 'character'), and I would like to output geocodes of each address in an n x 2 `data.frame` (lat and long). How would you write this in R, and is there an efficient way to do this? It would be great if you could show some examples.

Right now, I'm just running a for loop like this:

```
library(taRifx.geo) ## for geocode

hmm <- c()
for (i in (R2012)){
  hmm <- c(hmm, geocode(i, output = c("latlon", "latlona", "more", "all")))
}
```

But the result is an alternating single column of lat's and lon's:

```
$lon
[1] -122.1034

$lat
[1] 47.55304

$lon
[1] -122.1034

$lat
[1] 47.55304
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using Bing option with taRifx.geo in R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26075811/using-bing-option-with-tarifx-geo-in-r)

Comment: nope. completely different. All I'm asking is "how to create a data frame of lat's and lon's from a list of addresses."

Comment: Could you provide a small real sample and code?

Comment: that code shows you how. it provides an example of how to use an API to get the lat/lon in the format you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you force to use a `for` loop, you could do something like this.

```
library(tidyr)

R2012 <- c("Tokyo", "Paris")

lonlat <- list()

for(i in R2012){

    lonlat[[i]] <- geocode(i, output = c("latlon", "latlona", "more", "all"))
}

unnest(lonlat, city) 

#   city        lon      lat
#1 Tokyo 139.691706 35.68949
#2 Paris   2.352222 48.85661
```

But, I do not think a loop is necessary here. You may want to try something like this, instead.

```
foo <- geocode(R2012, output = c("latlon", "latlona", "more", "all"))
foo$city <- R2012

#         lon      lat  city
#1 139.691706 35.68949 Tokyo
#2   2.352222 48.85661 Paris
```